# Irrationality of square root of 2, as explained in the book, "How not to be wrong, the power of mathematical thinking"

Tags: geometry

I'm reading chapter 2, where the author describes a circle inscribing a square of unit 1. 
The inscribed square breaks up into four isosceles triangles. So the square's area is 4 times that of the triangle. That triangle in turn is what you get when you take a 1 x 1 square and cut it diagonally in half like a tuna fish sandwich. The area of the tuna fish sandwich is 1 x 1 = 1, so the area of each triangular half-sandwich is 1/2, and the area of the inscribed square is 4 x 1/2 or 2.

What I don't understand is why the author is multiplying 4 by 1/2 instead of 1/4. There is only 2 half sandwiches and halving them again would make each of it 1/4 of the original.

Comment: If you don't add a diagram it could be not many will even read the above...as I did, and I don't understand: how the square "breaks" into four isosceles triangles? By means of tracing two perpendicular diameters of the circle to the square's vertices?

Answer (score 0):

Each one of the four triangles can be thought of as half of a particular square (which is NOT the inscribed square), having as sides two circle radii. That's why their area is $1/2$.

[image]